# Question on proving the existence of a bijection between the ordered bases of $F^n$ and $\text{GL}_n (F)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I am trying to prove the existence of a bijection between the set of ordered bases for $F^n$, where $F$ is an arbitrary field, and $\text{GL}_n (F)$, the group of invertible $n \times n$ matrices over $F$. My attempted proof is below :

> Denote by $\mathcal{B}$ the set of bases of $\mathbb{F}^n$. Define $\varphi: \mathcal{B} \to \text{GL}_n (\mathbb{F})$ sending an ordered basis $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ to the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & \ldots & v_n \end{pmatrix}$ whose $i$th column is $v_i$ for each $i$. As $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ form a basis for $\mathbb{F}^n$, they are linearly independent, so the matrix $A$ is invertible and hence an element of $\text{GL}_n (\mathbb{F})$. If $\varphi(B_1) = \varphi(B_2)$ for $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$, then each column of the resulting matrix is equal, hence the ordered basis $B_1$ and $B_2$ are equal, so $\varphi$ is injective. Furthermore, let $A \in \text{GL}_n (\mathbb{F})$. As $A$ is invertible, its columns are linearly independent and hence forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Forming these columns into an ordered basis then gives a preimage for $A$, so $\varphi$ is surjective and hence bijective.

The biggest problem I have with this proof is that I don't know for sure what bases of $F^n$ I'm using for the domain and codomain of the transformation. I want to view a matrix as an encoding of a linear transformation, rather than a rectangular array of numbers, but the exact bases aren't clear. I can't say that the basis is $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$, because in that case, I'd have $T(v_i) = v_i$, which would give me the identity matrix. Since I'm giving a recipe for the $i$th column, it seems I'm letting $T(e_i) = v_i$ (where $e
_i$ is the $i$th standard basis vector), and I'm writing both the domain and codomain relative to the standard basis. It seems that the definition of $\text{GL}_n (F)$ does not take the choice of bases into account, and views any "rectangular array" as the same matrix.

Is this a correct understanding of what's going on?

Comment: You are stumbling into the difference between $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ and $\mathrm{GL}_n(F)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Finding_the_matrix_of_a_transformation

Comment: @AnneBauval I think I understand how to write down the bijection and how a matrix encodes a linear operator, but I'm not sure what, if any, specific basis I'm writing this matrix $A$ relative to. Is it simply the standard basis?

Comment: @Randall My understanding is that they're isomorphic, and an element of $\text{GL}(V)$ is encoded by an element of $\text{GL}_n (F)$. Does $\text{GL}_n 
(F)$, at least in the case of this proof, "forget" the choice of bases?

Comment: Yes, simply the standard basis.

Comment: @BradG  it's the opposite:  it fixes a basis to get the iso.  Different choices of bases give different isos.

Comment: @Randall So before writing down the isomorphism we'd say "we're going to write every matrix in $\text{GL}_n (F)$ relative to basis $\mathcal{B}$"? I was thinking it wouldn't make sense to define a map sending a basis $(v_1,\ldots, v_n)$ to a matrix relative to this basis. But if the basis is fixed beforehand, that makes sense.